# How to open a new tab on Page load using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

I am using javascript to open a new tab. I have done some coding when I run in my browser it is not opening a new tab when I click inside the browser window it is opening a new tab.

Attached the code 
JS code

```
var Light = Light || {};
 Light.Popup = {
    popName:  'Chip-LightPopup',
    alwaysPop: false, // refresh = new pop
    onNewTab: true,
    /**
     * 1: window onclick,
     * 2: window onload -> document onclick
    */
    eventType: 1,
    defaults: {
            width:                window.screen.width,
            height:                window.screen.height,
            left:                0,
            top:                0,
            location:        1,
            tollbar:        1,
            status:                1,
            menubar:        1,
            scrollbars:        1,
            resizable:        1
    },
    newWindowDefaults: {
            width:                window.screen.width - 20,
            height:                window.screen.height - 20
    },
    __newWindow: {
            scrollbars:        0
    },
    __counter : 0,
    create: function(link, options) {
            var optionsOriginal = options = options || {},
                    me = this;
            var popName = me.popName + '_' + (me.__counter++);
            var keys = ['onNewTab', 'eventType', 'cookieExpires', 'alwaysPop'];
            for(var i in keys) {
                    var key = keys[i];
                    if(typeof options[key] != 'undefined') {
                            eval('var ' + key + ' = options.' + key);
                            delete options[key];
                    } else {
                            eval('var ' + key + ' = me.' + key);
                    }
            }
            if(alwaysPop) {
                    cookieExpires = -1;
            }
            for(var i in me.defaults) {
                    if(typeof options[i] == 'undefined') {
                            options[i] = me.defaults[i];
                            if(!onNewTab && typeof me.newWindowDefaults[i] != 'undefined') {
                                    options[i] = me.newWindowDefaults[i];
                            }
                    }
            }
            for(var i in me.__newWindow) {
                    options[i] = me.__newWindow[i];
            }
            var params = [];
            for(var i in options) {
                    params.push(i + '=' + options[i]);
            }
            params = params.join(',');
            var executed = false;
            var execute = function() {
                    if(me.cookie(popName) === null && !executed) {
                            // Jul 5, 2013 - Anti Google Chrome Blocker
                            if(typeof window.chrome != 'undefined' && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Windows') != -1
                                    && typeof ___lastPopTime != 'undefined' && ___lastPopTime+5 > new Date().getTime()) {
                                    return;
                            }
                            executed = true;
                            if(onNewTab) {
                                    var w = window.open(link, popName);
                            } else {
                                    var w = window.open(link, '_blank', params);
                            }
                            w && w.blur(); // "w" may null on IE
                            window.focus();
                            me.cookie(popName, 1, cookieExpires);

                            ___lastPopTime = new Date().getTime();
                            if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac OS') != -1 && typeof window.chrome != 'undefined') {
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                            if(!w.innerWidth || !w.document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
                                                    me.create(link, optionsOriginal);
                                            }
                                    }, 100);
                            }
                    }
            }

            if(eventType == 2 || navigator.userAgent.match(/msie\s+(6|7|8)/i)) {
                    if (!window.addEventListener) {
                            window.attachEvent("onload", function(){
                                    document.body.attachEvent("onclick", execute);
                            });
                    } else {
                            window.addEventListener("load", function(){
                                    document.body.addEventListener("click", execute);
                            });
                    }
            }
            else if(eventType == 1) {
                    if (!window.addEventListener) {
                            window.attachEvent("onclick", execute);
                    } else {
                            window.addEventListener("click", execute);
                    }
            }
    },
    cookie: function(name, value, days) {
            if(arguments.length == 1) {
                    var cookieMatch = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name+"=[^;]+", "i"));
                    return (cookieMatch) ? decodeURIComponent(cookieMatch[0].split("=")[1]) : null;
            }
            if(days == null || typeof days == 'undefined') {
                    expires = '';
            } else {
                    var date;
                    if (typeof days == 'number') {
                            date = new Date();
                            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                    } else {
                            date = days;
                    }
                    expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString();
            }
            var value = escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value;
    }
```

};

Html code

```
Light.Popup.create('http://google.com', {alwaysPop: true});
```

Comment: Where is your code that actually opens the new tab? If it is `execute`, I think it is extremely clear that it only opens once you click on the body...

Comment: Popup is a terrible user experience, and will be blocked by browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

New windows / tabs will be blocked by popup blockers built into all modern browsers if the code to launch them does not come from a user triggered event.

The page loading is not a user triggered event.

Comment: If the new tab/window is opened in a `click` event, it won't be blocked, since it is an user triggered event.

Comment: @Oriol — Yes, because that is a user triggered event. The question isn't asking about clicks though (despite the code in the example).